# Problem returning a variable into a receiving object in C#

Tags: c#, object, return

I've been having a little problem with sharing variables to different objects, I was hoping to understand what I'm doing wrong and find a solution to the problem, I'm sort of new to programming using the object oriented programming language (C#) and I don't know what I'm doing wrong when it comes to that detail.

What I'm trying to do basically is to create a method which receives a user's input of some words as a string, it removes excess spaces from the string and creates a string array which holds every word within the string when it is seperated by a space.

The problem here is that the "return words;" at the end of the "RemoveSpace()" method isn't returning the value to "Test()" at all.
(I made sure to check that it was actually working using the debugger, but the RemoveSpace function is definitely working, just only within the method, and the returned value is seemingly ignored by the Test() method.)
(Also, to use Regex, use the "System.Text.RegularExpressions;" library)

What should I do? I've been racking my brain on it for a while and I'm out of ideas,
I'd much appreciate some help

```
public static class Reverso
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //User inputs the words as a string
        string words = Console.ReadLine();

        //Activates the Test object
        Test(words);
    }

    public static void Test(string words)
    {
        //Activates the RemoveSpace object.
        //It should receive the returned
        //value here, but not working
        RemoveSpace(words);

        //Takes words into a string array
        //seperated by spaces
        string[] parts = words.Split(' ');

        //Shows the result
        Console.WriteLine(words);
    }

    public static string RemoveSpace(string words)
    {
        //Using regex in order to remove more 
        //than 1 space between words and characters
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);
        words = regex.Replace(words, @" ");

        //Should return the value of the word
        //to the Test object, *not working*
        return words;
    }
}
```

Comment: You called RemoveSpace but you don't use the returned value.

Comment: Just to build on Ralf, strings are *immutable*, and any modification to them produces a new object, the original string is not modified. Unless you set words to the returned value of RemoveSpace, words will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reassign to `words` inside `RemoveSpace`, you need to pass the variable by reference:

```
public static string RemoveSpace(ref string words) // Use ref to pass by reference
```

Then inside Test, you would call the method like this:

```
RemoveSpace(ref words);
```

Without passing by reference, the `words` argument of `RemoveSpace` is a separate variable to the `words` variable in the calling method, so reassigning only affects the scope of `RemoveSpace`.

---

The usual approach would be to reassign the string that is returned from `RemoveSpace` inside `Test`:

```
public static void Test(string words)
{
    words = RemoveSpace(words);
```

Comment: I usually recommend to avoid ``ref`` when possible, and besides the RemoveSpace method already returns the correct string, the OP just isn't using it.

Comment: @Jono "_I usually recommend to avoid `ref` when possible_" Yeah, using `ref` wasn't a recommendation, it was an explanation as to why reassigning `words` within `RemoveSpace` wasn't affecting the variable in `Test`.